# How to make the body (or div) of fixed size stay always in the center of the page (even vertically!)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a 1024x768 body to stay always in the center of the page (top-bottom with same spacing, left-right too) however I'm having troubles in doing it.

I used the *trick* of spacing from top by 50%, then I positioned (absolutely) the body at -384px, which is half of 768.

However this method gives me a problem: if your window is smaller than 768px, you get a scrollbar but a part of the upperside of the body get cut, without any possibility to scroll up (I can still scroll down).

How to solve it?

**Edit 1:**
Here is some code:

- JS.Fiddle (fullscreen): http://jsfiddle.net/FireDragonDoL/TGjN8/6/embedded/result/
- JS.Fiddle (normal): http://jsfiddle.net/FireDragonDoL/TGjN8/6/

Html code that can be printed on a simple html web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
/**
 *     Change the basic background color of the page
 */
html
{
    background-color: blue;
}

/**
 *     Set the body as a 1024 x 768 rectangle in center of the screen
 */
body
{
    background-color:                   red;
    font-family:      TradeGothic, sans-serif;
    margin-left:                       -512px;
    margin-top:                        -384px;
    position:                        absolute;
    height:                             768px;
    width:                             1024px;
    left:                                 50%;
    top:                                  50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
some text
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 768px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TGjN8/9/ (fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TGjN8/9/show/ )

Comment: Woah, thanks a lot!!! May I ask you why it works? I don't get exactly the point in min-width, while I completely understand the 100% height (but I thought it was something default). I didn't expect an answer from a 50k reputation person to this...thanks a lot!

Comment: Adding also: position: relative; is it there to make the viewport relative to the window? (at 0;0)

Comment: You're welcome. `position: relative` anchors the absolutely positioned `body` to `html` and `min-*` prevents `html` becoming smaller than `body` which ensures scrolling. So, "yes".

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer was really helpful and interesting. I learnt lot from it!