# Div won't stretch the full height of the page (yup, I've Googled plenty)

Tags: css, html, height, footer, stretch

I'm trying to stretch the content of a div the height of the page. I've Googled the problem and so far nothing works. The whole thing is starting to give me a headache. Perhaps someone more experienced could take a look at my code? The full stylesheet is >400 lines, so I'm including what is (hopefully) relevant.

"Wrapper" takes up 100% of the page height, whereas "contentShadow" stretches only to the height of the text in the div "content".

Edit: as far as I can tell, every container has its height set to 100%, which whould make "contentShadow" 100% as well. Right...?

Edit 2: **I'm starting to see the problem, but don't know how to solve it**. While the following code will keep the footer down, it also means that since .wrapper doesn't have height:100%, "contentShadow" will not stretch. The question then is how I keep my footer down while changing this code:

```
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
margin: 0 auto -37px;
```

}

To this:

```
.wrapper {
height: 100%;
```

}

---

Basic structure of the page:

```
<div id="body">
<div id="headerWrapper"></div>
<div id="wrapper">  
    <div id="contentShadow">
        <div id="#contentWrapper">
            <div id="content">
            <!-- contentshadow stretches the height of this content and no further, but SHOULD stretch the height of the entire page -->
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="push"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Css rules relevant to these divs:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

#headerWrapper {
height: 314px;
width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -37px;
}

#contentShadow {
min-height: 100%;
width: 994px;
background-image: url(../images/contentShadow.png);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
   margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

#contentWrapper {
min-height: 100%;
width: 940px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-right: 16px;
padding-bottom: 16px;
padding-left: 16px;
padding-top: 17px;
background-color: #EDECEC;
overflow: hidden;
}

#content {   
min-height: 100%;
}

.footer, .push,  {
height: 37px;
}

.footer {
background: white;   
clear: both;
height: 37px;
}
```

Comment: I can't give you a direct answer mate, but watch the answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122904/how-to-make-the-body-or-div-of-fixed-size-stay-always-in-the-center-of-the-pag I think merging that answer with all you know will bring you to the result (expecially things about *html* tag)

Answer (score 4):

You have really wrong code:

- `.wrapper` matched `<div class="wrapper">` not `<div id="wrapper">`.
- `<div id="#contentWrapper">` is not correct, you should try `<div id="contentWrapper">`
- `height: auto;` is the problem. The wrapper needs to be 100% height, not auto...
- the `height: 100%` after `height: auto !important` doesn't make sens, because of the !important keyword.

Comment: Changing wrapper height to 100% will actually stretch contentShadow the height of the page. Unfortunately it also brakes my sticky footer. :/ The current code under .wrapper is what keeps the footer down.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the default margins and padding, have you tried this?

```
body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The contentShadow must have overflow: auto. Try this

```
body, html { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#container { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; display: block; }


<body>
  <div id="container">
      This should fill the page!
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for the better part of my life, but I just solved it for myself, so I'm sharing, just in case somebody else can benefit.

My HTML/BODY selector is set to height:100%.

My container div within the HTML/BODY selector is set to min-height:800px.

My CONTENT div inside of the CONTAINER div didn't have a height, and I had the issue of the div not stretching to the bottom of the page. When I inspected this div, I noticed that for some reason, it was stretching way below its container div, pushing it up and creating that annoying space at the bottom of the page. Once I placed a height on that inside DIV, the issue went away for me.

I hope this helps.